# How to compile and run an ES6 file with node when using babel6?

Tags: babeljs

I installed the latest version 6 of **`babel`**, **`babel-core`** and **`babel-loader`**.

How can I run an ES6 file in Node with Babel6?

Previously I would run the command

```
babel-node server.js
```

but now I get this message:

```
The CLI has been moved into the package `babel-cli`. See http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/.
```

None of the instructions on that page say how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The message could be clearer. You've installed the `babel` package and you should have installed the `babel-cli` package.

```
npm uninstall babel
npm install babel-cli
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon installing `babel-cli` I also had to specify the `es2015` loader and to specifically use my local `babel-node` package since I don't have it installed globally.

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel-node --presets es2015 server.js
```